# How to disable account in failed login

Tags: vb.net

Is there any code idea on disabling account temporarily, if you failed to login correctly 3 times?. we are using vb.net, thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible but we need to see how far you've done and at least a code. It's possible to run in a for loop.

Comment: Please read [Ask] an take the [tour].  this is not even close to how to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

While you still need to provide *some* code, it's easy enough to provide a bit of code. The following is assuming that you've some kind of login form:

1. Declare an integer in your login form.

   ```
   Dim Tries As Integer = 0
   ```
2. On clicking `Login`, check if `Tries < 3`:

   ```
   If Tries < 3 Then
       If Login Then 'Replace Login with what you're doing to authenticate the user.
           Tries = 0
           'Do Something.
       Else
           Tries += 1
           'Do Something else.
       End If
   ElseIf Tries = 3 Then
       'Block the user from logging in and send a message.
   End If
   ```

This is the basics of authentication with failure to login 3 times. If you want to wait `x` minutes for the user to log in again, store the current system date and time (and `Tries`) somewhere and then retrieve it when the user tries to login again. When retrieved, compare the date & time to the current date and time, then decide if the user should be able to login.